# jquery form plugin saving duplicate entries to mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, jquery-plugins

i am in the process of designing an admin panel for a friends website. i am using the jquery form plugin to submit a form without refreshing the page. as this form requires an image to be uploaded to the server, im unable to use ajax which im a little more familiar with.

here is my form/jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function() { 

                $('#submitform').live('click', function()           { 
                           $("#preview").html('');
                    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Processing...."/>');
                $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                            target: '#preview'
            }).submit();

                });
            }); 
    </script>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='pages/addprodprocess.php'>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Product Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="prodname" id="prodname" placeholder="Product Name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Description:</td> <td><textarea name="proddesc" id="proddesc" placeholder="Product Description"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Price:</td> <td><input type="text" name="prodprice" id="prodprice" placeholder="Price eg. 7.99"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Category:</td> <td>
<?php
   $getcats = mysql_query("select * from product_cats");
    if(mysql_num_rows($getcats) == 0){
    echo '<select id="prodcat" name="prodcat" disabled="disabled">';
           echo '<option>Please create a category first!</option>';
           echo '</select>';
           }else{ 
           echo '<select id="prodcat" name="prodcat">';
   while($cats = mysql_fetch_array($getcats)){
   echo '<option value="'.$cats['cat_id'].'">'.$cats['cat_name'].'</option>';
   }
   echo ' </select>';

   }
   ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product image:</td> <td><input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" /></td>
</tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitform"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div>
```

my form/jquery seems to work fine, the problem is processing the form on submit.
when submitted it is sent to my 'addprodprocess.php' page for processing which works fine, BUT when saving the form values to mysql, it saves duplicates (same data more than once) to the table!

here is my processing page:

```
<?php
$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass'); 
if (!$link2) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('database'); 

//ADD PRODUCT
if (isset($_FILES['photoimg'])) {
$path = "../products/";
       $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
    if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

            if(strlen($name) && strlen($_POST['prodname']) && strlen($_POST['proddesc']) && strlen($_POST['prodprice']) && strlen($_POST['prodcat']))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                    if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name))
                                {
                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (`product_name`,`product_desc`,`product_img`,`product_price`,`product_cat`) VALUES('".$_POST['prodname']."','".$_POST['proddesc']."','".$name."','".$_POST['prodprice']."','".$_POST['prodcat']."')");

                                    echo "<img src='products/".$name."'  class='preview' height='75' width='75'>";
                                }
                            else{
                                echo "failed";
                                }
                        }
                        else{
                        echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
                        }                   
                        }
                        else{
                        echo "Invalid file format..";   
                        }
                }

            else{
                echo "All fields MUST be filled in!";
                }

            exit;
        }
        }  
        ?>
```

anyone who could help me out, it would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

before the INSERT run a SELECT and make sure it returns NULL.